# How can I send a JSON object from a Python script to jQuery?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json, getjson

I've looked through APIs and all sorts of resources, but I can't seem to get the hang of fetching a JSON object from a Python script using AJAX. I'm sure the issue is with how I'm dealing with the JSON object.

First, in a python script on my server, I generate and print a JSON array

```
import json
print "Content-type: application/json"
print 
print json.dumps(['Price',{'Cost':'99'}])
```

Then, in a separate html file, I try something like

```
<body>
<div id="test">
</div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/makeJSON.py", function(data) {
        $('#test').html("JSON Data: " + data.Price);
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

But I don't get anything. I'm sure that `data.Price` is wrong, but I'm also pretty certain that I should be doing something instead of just printing the results of `json.dumps`

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance, and sorry if this is an obvious question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your case you have enclosed the JSON response in an `array`. To access price you need to access `data[0]`. You need to structure your JSON data properly.

The following changes in your Python script should allow you to access `data.Price`. Let me know in case you still face any issues.

```
   import json
   print "Content-type: application/json"
   print 
   response={'Price':54,'Cost':'99'}
   print(json.JSONEncoder().encode(response))
```

Comment: No problem, but we need to structure the response JSON data correctly. Let's say both `Price` and `Cost` are simple keys in a python dictionary, when sent to the client can be accessed using `data.Price` and `data.Cost` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more context to what you're trying to do. Can you just hard-code the JSON object into the HTML? Or, are you trying to do something more dynamic, like AJAX?

For the former, view the HTML source of the page that Python generates. It must look something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var MY_GLOBAL_JSON_OBJECT = { ... };
</script>
```

Or you could just spit out the JSON object inside the function that's actually using it instead of assigning it first to a global variable.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I got the script returning the correct JSON object. And yes, it's dynamic, so I can;t hardcode it. The only issue now is I don't know how to access the stored values, as `data.Price` doesn't work