# python gae Render an image returned from ajax post json format

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json, google-app-engine

failing to render an image returned by ajax post in json format.

How do I render the image which is posted by ajax to the GAE request handler?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        var data = {'imageSrc' : $(this).parent().find('img').attr('src')};
        console.log(data);
        var request = $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: "/i",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data, status) {
                console.log(data, status);
            },
        });

        request.done(function(msg) {
            window.location = '/i'
            alert("Request succeeded: " + msg );
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    });
});
```

**GAE**

```
def post(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    self.response.content_type = 'application/json'
    # imageSrc = self.request.POST['imageSrc']
    # logging.info("DoubleNumbers called for:" + imageSrc)
    # jsonData = {"img" : imageSrc}
    # logging.info(jsonData)
    # js = json.dumps(jsonData)
    # self.response.write(simplejson.dumps(jsonData['img']))
    self.response.headers.add_header('content-type', 'application/json', charset='utf-8')
    # self.response.write(js)
    # self.response.write('''<img src="''')
    # self.response.write(json.JSONEncoder(jsonData['img']))
    # self.response.write('''">''')
    t = json.loads(self.request.POST['imageSrc'])
    self.response.write('''<html><body><img src="''')
    self.response.write(t['imageSrc'])
    self.response.write('''"></body></html>''')
```

**UPDATE**
I'm getting the **img src** as JSON data But still **failing to output/render it.**
I changed my JS script to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        var data = {'imageSrc' : $(this).parent().find('img').attr('src')};

        var request = $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: "/i",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: "json",
        }).done(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                });
    });
});
```

& my **main.py** file as:

```
def post(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    data = json.loads(self.request.body)
    z = data['imageSrc']
    logging.info(z)
    logging.info(data)
    self.response.write(json.dumps(data))
    self.response.write('''<html><body><img src="http://mysite:8080%s"></body></html>'''%z)
```

How do I render the returned JSON data (img src file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace:

```
data: JSON.stringify(data),
```

with:

```
data: data,
```

and to get imageSrc in the server:

```
imageSrc = self.request.get('imageSrc')
```

**UPDATE: Redirecting to GET page**

JS

```
// Add GET parameters to an URL
// Ex.:  site.com/?param=value
function addUrlSep( url ) {
    var sep = (url.indexOf('?') > -1) ? '&' : '?';
    return url + sep; }
function buildUrl( base, key, value ) {
    url = addUrlSep( base );
    return url + key + '=' + value; }

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click( function(){

        base_url = "/i";

        url = buildUrl( base_url, 'imageSrc', 'https://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo6w.png' );

        window.location = url;  // Redirects to the URL

    });
});
```

PY

```
def get(self):
    z = self.request.get( 'imageSrc' )
    logging.info(z)
    self.response.write( "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><img src='{}'></body></html>" .format( z ) )

def post(self):
    pass
```

Comment: no, still i can't render the image, I changed my .py file `self.response.write('''<html><body><img src="''')
self.response.write(imageSrc)
self.response.write('''"></body></html>''')`
I got error as KeyError: "No key 'imageSrc': Not an HTML form submission (Content-Type: application/json)"

Comment: Try: imageSrc = self.request.get('imgSrc')

Comment: http post request status is 200 but I get `parseerror` & the image is not rendered.

Comment: Where are you getting 'parseerror'? Can you post the response you are getting from the server, using a random URL ?

Comment: if I use JSON in my `.py` script as `def post(self):
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
data = json.loads(self.request.body)
z = data['imageSrc']
self.response.write(json.dumps(response))` I get error as `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded` for **data** attribute

Comment: I'm getting the value send from ajax post in the server `main.py` file I have updated the code above the `logging.info(data)` shows the data as `{u'imageSrc': u'img/allofthethings.png'}`, but the Only issue is I can't render it, so currently I'm checking 4 some alternatives & looking into this http://stackoverflow.com/q/4315900/2541442 If you can suggest some options, would be gr8.

Comment: You just want to show the image?  You are using `<html><body><img src="http://mysite:8080%s"></body></html>`, that include the <HTML> tags.  To render this, you'll need to write the response inside an iframe, or replace the entire document. Try `document.open("text/html"); document.write( data ); document.close();`, in your 'done' function.

Comment: And why the `self.response.write(json.dumps(data))` line ?

Comment: `self.response.write(json.dumps(data))` for debugging nothing specific, & how do I use the above code in my response function? would it be something like this: 
`.done(function(data){
    var url = "/i";
    var txt="<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><img src=http://localhost:8080'"+data+"'></body></html>";
    window.location.href = url;
    document.open("text/html");
    document.write( txt );
    document.close();
    });`
I tried the above code but didn't work.

Comment: Also I'd like to add that I'm looking to render the response (the image) on another URL. say from http://mysite.com/image to http://mysite.com/selectedimage after the ajax post.

Comment: On the server, remove `self.response.write(json.dumps(data))`, and send only the URL: `self.response.write(z)`.  On JS, `.done(function(data){ 
 var txt = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><img src='"+data+"'></body></html>"; 
 document.open("text/html");
 document.write( txt );
 document.close();
});`.  Instead of using an URL like, `img/allofthethings.png`, use `/img/allofthethings.png` with a bar.

Comment: hmm, I changed the code as you mentioned but he document at URL `/i` still shows as blank.. the header response status is 200 & response shown is `img/interesting.jpg` missing the `HTML Doctype` any ideas. I've upload the [code here](http://pastebin.com/MsQHKdwa) if you would like to take a close look. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you click the button the page goes blank ? Try to view the source code of the blank page.

Comment: checked the src its blank.

Comment: wow.. one last thing, I tried the code & the ajax post the data & updates the current page itself, is there a way I can update a different page, say from current URL is `http://mysite.com/i.html` & render the image on `http://mysite.com/xyz.html`?

Comment: You can use GET instead of POST method on `/xyz.html`, and redirect to it.  Or use a [hidden form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389646/send-post-data-on-redirect-with-javascript-jquery).

Comment: ok, so do I use the GET in `.py` or the `.js` by changing ajax POST to GET & then use the `.html()` with a redirect.

Comment: `self.request.body` doesn't worked with the get function here. So, I made some changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts, I nearly went bald pulling my hair off searching for options to get this silly task done, Thanks. Up voting for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript, you need something like:

```
request.done(function(msg) {
        window.body = msg;
        alert("Request succeeded: " + msg );
});
```

I can tell this is just an exercise, but what you're doing here doesn't make much sense.  You're not actually sending the image to the server, you're just sending the url to the server, getting it back, and then having the browser load the url.

Comment: hmm, ok, yeap I might be just sending the URL, I updated js with `window.body = msg;` it didn't work either, any ideas? & how can I send the image instead of URL if that what's happening?